# How to make an in-window pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a pop up that'd open in the same webpage and wouldn't open in a different window using Javascript? How to darken the background behind the pop up when it is opened?

Comment: This is called a Modal window.

Comment: You are talking about alerts, right?

Comment: Are you talking about a overlay?

Comment: usually I encourage people to learn to do things in pure javascript before they look for a framework solution, but a modal dialog / window is a rather complex construct, so, as the answers have stated, have a look at jQuery, dojo, prototype, extJS...they all have solutions for this

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery Dialog for that.First create a div in your HTML Include Jquery.js and jquery.UI both and also put modal =true for darken background

```
 <div id="DialogBox"></div>

 $("#DialogBox").dialog({
                    height: 600,
                    width: 600,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "Close",
                            click: function () {                          
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }]
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery plugins like jquery popup overly ,inthe link below there is 250 plugins for pop up and all have documentation , jquery popup overly also listed there ,check the link below

[250 jquery popup plugins](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-popup-window/)